# How to input mask value to Convolution1D layer

Tags: keras, convolution, masking

I need to feed variable length sequences into my model.

My model is `Embedding + LSTM + Conv1d + Maxpooling + softmax`.

When I set `mask_zero = True` in `Embedding`, I fail to compile at `Conv1d`.

How can I input mask value in `Conv1d` or is there another solution?

Comment: does it compile if the LSTM is after the convolutional and maxpooling layers?

Comment: @convolutionBoy it still failed if the LSTM after Conv, I have found the issue in github, except RNN and Timedistributed Layer, the else all can't support mask

Answer (score 8):

The `Masking` layer expects every downstream layer to support masking, which is not the case of the `Conv1D` layer. Fortunately, there is another way to apply masking, using the Functional API:

```py
inputs = Input(...)
mask = Masking().compute_mask(inputs) # <= Compute the mask
embed = Embedding(...)(inputs)
lstm = LSTM(...)(embed, mask=mask) # <= Apply the mask
conv = Conv1D(...)(lstm)
...
model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[...])
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this solution works if the data type is integer (for example if the input are words or characters to be embedded). Is there a way to do this with float data (for example if the input is some data series of some physical data?), where embedding is not appropriate?

Comment: If you tried and it doesn't work with floats, then a last resort option is to write your own custom layers: class YourCustomLayer(keras.layers.Layer): ... def call(self, inputs, mask): ...

Answer (score 7):

Conv1D layer does not support masking at this time. Here is an [open issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/411) on the keras repo.

Depending on the task you might be able to get away with embedding the `mask_value` just like the other values in the sequence and apply global pooling (as you're doing now).

Comment: Thanks for answer. In your solution, I remove mask_value = True,and give padding a embedding vector, when after maxpooling, the padding timestep will gradually be neglected during training. Did you mean that? 
Or the solution in the github issue, I insert a tensor [1,1,1,0,0,0] which 0 represent pad, I multyply this tensor with conv output then input to the maxpooling layer? How do you think this solution

Comment: It's not clear to me how it works. Could you please provide code examples? Thanks.