# Tensorflow Keras: Problems to handle variable length input, using generator?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, generator, tf.keras, tf.data.dataset

We want to train our model on varying input dimensions. Every input in a given batch and across batches has different dimensions.

We cannot resize our input (since we’ll lose our microscopic features). Now, since we cannot resize our input, converting them into batches of `numpy array` becomes impossible. In order to handle this now I have made the **list** for the input and each list of element contained `(height, width, 1)`. Height is variable size and width is constant.

Sometime my input excessively large. In order to do that I have plan to use model.fit_generator(). In this, We find the max height and width of input in a batch and pad every other input with zeros so that every input in the batch has an equal dimension. Now we can easily convert it to a numpy array or a tensor and pass it to the fit_generator(). The model automatically learns to ignore the zeros and learns features from the intended portion from the padded input. This way we have a batch with equal input dimensions but every batch has a different shape (due to difference in max height and width of input across batches).

Now until here, I described the things what I have learned and what I have plan to do with variable input data. But I am stuck with the following confusions:

1- I have plan to use CNN first and then LSTM on that. I am using tensorflow keras. There, we have the facility of [padding and masking](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding) . However, As for as I know that LSTM can work on masking and padding ignore 0-padded values. However, I am concerned about the CNN (does CNN ignores 0-padded values), because my padded input will first feed to CNN. I have seen some discussion in the following links:

1. [How to apply masking layer to sequential CNN model in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53977616/how-to-apply-masking-layer-to-sequential-cnn-model-in-keras)
2. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/411

In these link, they mentioned that Unfortunately masking is not yet supported by the Keras Conv layers. However, now we can see alot of development and advancements specifically in the form of tensorflow Keras. **So I am wondering that now tensorflow keras can support masking input?**

2- To use the generator, we can use custom keras generator. For that I went through a vary good [tutorial](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly). I made the mind to use this. But I am wondering is there any advance built-in facility in tensorflow keras to use generator and save me to write custom keras generator?

Comment: Note: If someone wants to see my code. Feel free to ask. I will share. Thanks